# Problems understanding model notation in LPs

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming

today I came across a paper that uses a type of model notation I have never come across before. These are the objective function and constraints I don't quite understand. I am specifically interested in what the dots in front of the capital letters mean. For example, for $i.NC=1$, does this mean that it only applies to all $NC$ of index $i$?

Likewise, how do I understand the sum signs with the $\wedge$ symbol?

\begin{align}
I)~\min\sum_{j,b}^{}j.W\cdot l_{jb}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
II)~\sum_{i:i.B}^{}p_{jit}\le l_{jb}~~~\forall j,t,b
\end{align}
\begin{align}
III)~\sum_{i,t:i.NC=1\wedge i.B=b}^{}p_{jit}\le 3~~~\forall j,b
\end{align}
\begin{align}
VI)~\sum_{i,t:i.SUN=1\wedge i.B=b}^{}p_{jit}\le 1~~~\forall j,b\end{align}
\begin{align}
V)~\sum_{i,t:i.B=b}^{}i.SAS\cdot p_{jit}\le j.AS\cdot l_{jb}~~~\forall j,b\end{align}
\begin{align}
VI)~p_{jit}+\sum_{k:k.B=b\wedge k.NC\neq1}^{}p_{jk(t+1)}\le 1~~~\forall j,t,i:i.NC=1\end{align}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The $\wedge$ simply means "and". So for example, constraint III is telling you to sum over all pair of $i$ and $t$ such that $i.NC = 1$ *and* $i.B=b$.

As for what the authors mean by the "." notation itself (such as $i.NC$), that is impossible to say for certain without context; it is not a standard notation as far as I know. But I would be willing to wager that each $i$ comes from set, and for each $i$ there are a bunch of related parameters, including $NC$ and $B$. For example, in a minimum cost flow problem, each edge $e$ has the parameters "cost" and "capacity". Normally, we think of these as vectors/functions and write them as $c_e$ and $u_e$ (or $c(e)$ and $u(e)$. However, if you wanted to emphasize that these are properties of the edge (NB: this has no mathematical meaning but could improve pedagogy) you could choose to write them as $e.c$ and $e.u$ (or even $e.cost$ and $e.capacity$). The reason I think this is what the authors mean is that this is the syntax that many popular programming languages use if you want to access a property of a specific object.

Comment: The ^ character is called a caret, not a carat. Also $\wedge$ is known as the logical AND symbol. This has nothing to do with the caret symbol so I suggest updating your answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I have removed the incorrect information.